# WCF and Intermediate Devices & Issues with external link

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

First time I am hosting a WCF service on an internal UAT server (IIS 7).

This service should be accessible over web at a an address like https://abc.com/MyApp/MyService.svc

It should be accessible through http and https

1. How do I define the endpoints in this case??
2. When I enabled both http and https and kept address as blank address=""  SOAP location in the WSDL showed the address with name of the server (`https://servername/MyService.svc`) instead of `https://abc.com/MyApp/MyService.svc`.
   When I load this address - `https://abc.com/MyApp/MyService.svc` in SOAP UI the endpoint address changes to `https://servername/MyService.svc`
3. Do I need to use host header? When and how to use host header?
4. How to define relative address in this scenario?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was due to the SSL offloader which was infornt of the server. For noe we got rid of it and service works just fine.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/05/13/wcf-and-intermediate-devices.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This question is very vague, but here's a good primer you should read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the binding of the web site in IIS? The URI is built off of what information is stored there, so that could potentially help.

Comment: no..i have not tried changing the binding. It is just basichttpinding.

Comment: @Shetty: Not the binding of the WCF service. I am talking about the binding of the web site itself in IIS. For instance *:80 is the typical default.

Comment: oh sorry..443 is also enabled.One problem we have is that port 80 is not open. IT operations have some reasons for doing this (domething to do with ssl offloader).but it will be open again soon.I am not sure if that is causing any problem. now i am okay to get it work with only https.

Comment: @Shetty: Do you have full control of IIS? Or just your application?

Comment: Modify your [web site bindings](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/bindings/binding) to have an explicit reference to the URL you plan to be accessed. If you don't access the IIS box using the internal name you can even try making that the only binding.

Comment: :Thanks for trying to help me out. I figured out that it was because of the SSL offloader which was infront of the web server. WE got rd of it by time being and service works well with basic httpbinding with no configuration changes. I also added host header for https in IIS.